# Installing Java 19 on macOS 12.01 Monterey manually (without Homebrew)

Tags: terminal, install, permission, java

I would like to install [`Java 19`](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-mac) from [Arm 64 Compressed Archive](https://download.oracle.com/java/19/latest/jdk-19_macos-aarch64_bin.tar.gz) on my Mac running `macOS 12.01 Monterey` and `Chip Apple M1 Pro` *without using **Homebrew***.

I unzipped the file in the folder `jdk-19.jdk` to `/usr/local`.

I changed the ownership as follows:

`sudo chown -R root:wheel /usr/local/jdk-19.jdk`

and/or:

`sudo chown -R joseluisbz:staff /usr/local/jdk-19.jdk`

and I was trying to give Terminal complete control over the disk using this [tutorial](https://iboysoft.com/howto/fix-zsh-permission-denied-in-mac-terminal.html).

```
% ls -al /usr/local                                                                                                                                            
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   7 root        wheel  224 Sep 27 20:12 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 root        wheel  352 Oct 17  2021 ..
drwxr-xr-x  15 root        wheel  480 Sep 27 22:19 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 joseluisbz  staff  128 Dec 20  2021 include
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root        wheel  128 Sep 27 19:44 jdk-19.jdk
drwxr-xr-x   9 joseluisbz  staff  288 Mar 10  2022 lib
drwxr-xr-x   3 root        wheel   96 Mar  2  2022 share
%
```

With `nano` I created `~/.zshenv` using this [tutorial](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/) with these contents:

```
#export JAVA_HOME=$(/Users/joseluisbz/Downloads/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home)
#export JAVA_HOME=$(/Applications/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home)
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/local/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home)
```

But, when I source the file, I get:

```
source ~/.zshenv
/Users/joseluisbz/.zshenv:3: permission denied: /Applications/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
```

- **What am I doing wrong?**
- **What other alternatives can I try?**

Comment: Well, you didn't actually follow the tutorial you link to (it's correct there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What am I doing wrong?**

When setting `JAVA_HOME`, you are using this notation: `$()`, which `zsh` interprets as [command substitution](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_7.html): **command substitution** tells `zsh` to interpret the path within the brackets as a command, execute it, and return the result.

In the specific case of `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/local/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home)`, `zsh` tries to execute `/Applications/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home`, but since it is a directory and not an executable file, it fails and displays this error:

`permission denied: /Applications/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home`

To fix the issue, in your file `~/.zshenv` change from:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/local/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home)`

to

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).